# Deleção com integridade referencial MYSQL

Tags: mysql

O mundo do projeto é o seguinte:

Tenho um cliente, onde eu cadastro para ele, recados, noticias, faço upload de fotos, onde existe agendas também. So que quando estou para deletar ele, antes preciso deletar tudo dele, pois o banco não permite por integridade referencial. Até ai tudo ok, mas na parte de noticias, tenho outra tabela que liga as imagens da noticias a aquela noticia, e esta ligação é feita por uma tabela onde tenho o código da noticia e o código da imagem, na verdade é uma ligação muitos para muitos. Então ai que está o problema, para mim deletar o campo da tabela imagens referentes a aquela noticia é necessário que eu delete antes este relacionamento entre a imagem e a noticia, porem se eu deletar, não tenho condições de saber de que publicação é aquela imagem.

Como posso resolver isto ?

Segue o que tenho feito até agora.

```
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_CLIENTES_AGENDA WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN ='" . $COD_IDENT_CLIEN . "'");

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_IMAGENS
                            WHERE COD_SEQUN_IMAGM IN 
                            (
                                    SELECT COD_SEQUN_IMAGM FROM tbl_PUBLICACOESxIMAGENS
                                WHERE COD_IDENT_PUBLI IN
                                (
                                            SELECT COD_IDENT_CLIEN FROM tbl_PUBLICACOES
                                    WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN = " . $COD_IDENT_CLIEN . "
                                )
                            )");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_PUBLICACOES WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN = '" . $COD_IDENT_CLIEN . "'");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_RECADOS WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN = '" . $COD_IDENT_CLIEN . "");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_CLIENTES_PF WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN ='" . $COD_IDENT_CLIEN . "'");
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_CLIENTES WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN ='" . $COD_IDENT_CLIEN . "'");
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_IMAGENS I INNER JOIN tbl_CLIENTESxIMAGENS CI ON I.COD_SEQUN_IMAGM = CI.COD_SEQUN_IMAGM WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN ='" . $COD_IDENT_CLIEN . "' ");
    while ($linha2 = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $arquivo = "../uploads/{$linha2['TXT_FILEN_IMAGN']}";
        unlink($arquivo);
    }
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_CLIENTESxIMAGENS WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN ='" . $COD_IDENT_CLIEN . '"');
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM tbl_IMAGENS WHERE COD_SEQUN_IMAGM IN
(
    SELECT COD_SEQUN_IMAGM FROM tbl_CLIENTESxIMAGENS WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN = '" . $COD_IDENT_CLIEN . "'
)");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN, P.COD_IDENT_PUBLI, I.COD_SEQUN_IMAGM, I.TXT_FILEN_IMAGN
                                        FROM
                                        (
                                        SELECT * FROM tbl_CLIENTES WHERE COD_IDENT_CLIEN = '" . $COD_IDENT_CLIEN . "'
                                        ) C 

                                        LEFT JOIN
                                        (
                                        SELECT * FROM tbl_PUBLICACOES
                                        ) P
                                        ON P.COD_IDENT_CLIEN = C.COD_IDENT_CLIEN

                                        LEFT JOIN
                                        (
                                        SELECT * FROM tbl_PUBLICACOESxIMAGENS
                                        ) PI
                                        ON PI.COD_IDENT_PUBLI = P.COD_IDENT_PUBLI

                                        LEFT JOIN
                                        (
                                        SELECT * FROM tbl_IMAGENS
                                        ) I
                                        ON I.COD_SEQUN_IMAGM = PI.COD_SEQUN_IMAGM  WHERE I.COD_SEQUN_IMAGM is not NULL;

                                        ");
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $arquivo = "../uploads/{$linha['TXT_FILEN_IMAGN']}";
        unlink($arquivo);
    }
```

> É necessário seguir uma ordem para deleção e ela é: Deletar Agenda, Deletar ImagemxPublicação, Deletar Imagem, Deletar Publicação, Deletar Recados, Deletar cliente_Pf e por ultimo Deletar cliente.

Está ocorrendo um erro quando eu deleto a tabela de PublicaçõesxImagens, ele acusa o seguinte erro:

> 11:18:57   DELETE FROM tbl_PUBLICACOESxIMAGENS WHERE COD_SEQUN_IMAGM IN ('64,65,66,67,68,70,71')   1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '64,65,66,67,68,70,71'  0.374 sec

A query que fiz é a seguinte:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_PUBLICACOESxIMAGENS WHERE COD_SEQUN_IMAGM IN ('64,65,66,67,68,70,71')
```

Comment: Você não precisa necessariamente deletar o cliente, pode criar um campo onde informa se ele está ativo/inativo

Comment: Porem ja tenho este campo, mas este exemplo é caso o cara não quiser mais aquele cliente, é preciso dar esta escolha .

Comment: Na verdade é pouco provável que deva deletar o cliente. `DELETE` é comando mais mal utilizado do SQL. Mas se vai fazer o estrago, então faça por completo, destrua tudo o que tem relação com aquilo, começando pelo que está na ponta. Só você sabe tudo o que é preciso fazer. Mas reforço que a remoção de um item não deveria ser possível desta forma. Se tem elementos que dependem dele, não deve deletar. Simples assim. Só deveria ser permitido quando realmente não tem dependências. Parece ser um requisito inventado.

Comment: Porque a ideia é o seguinte, se o cara criar cliente errado, ou mais profundo se o cara ficar um tempo sem colocar conteúdo para aquele cliente, e simplesmente ser necessário apagar todo o conteúdo para aquela certa pessoa, pois não haverá mais vinculo algum, são nestas opções que eu preciso dar esta chance. E sim eu sei que tem que fazer, porem se eu deletar os items da tabela publicacaoximagem eu perco quais são as imagens ligadas a aquela publicação, tem algum jeito de guarda-las e depois fazer uma query comparando ?

Comment: Porque não deixar o SGBD gerir isto por ti? Pesquisa por ON DELETE CASCADE? Em todas as tabelas que tenham uma foreign key usas o "ON DELETE CASCADE" e quando um registo dor removido da tabela "pai" as tabelas filhas serão automaticamente actualizadas.

Comment: mais será deletada as informações ou apenas gerara um update nas tabelas @bruno

Comment: Serão deletados todos os registos. Se necessário posso criar um pequeno exemplo para você!

Comment: Por favor faz isto ? @bruno

Comment: Se possível utilize os meus dados como o próprio exemplo.

Comment: recomendo utilizar o PDO, o mysq_query será descontinuado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como indicado nos comentários não necessitas de fazer esta gestão manualmente. **Se o teu objectivo é mesmo apagar os registos de todas as tabelas** podes usar a opção [ON DELETE CASCADE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Segue aqui um pequeno exemplo usando duas das suas tabelas.

```
create table tbl_CLIENTES (
    idCliente bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL
  , loginCliente varchar(60) NOT NULL default ''
  , nome varchar(250) NOT NULL default ''
  , PRIMARY KEY  (idCliente)
  , KEY `user_login_key` (loginCliente)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

create table tbl_CLIENTES_AGENDA 
(
    id  int unsigned NOT NULL
  , idCliente   bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL
  , email varchar(60) NOT NULL default ''
  , PRIMARY KEY  (id)
  , FOREIGN KEY (idCliente) REFERENCES tbl_CLIENTES(idCliente) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)Engine=INNODB;
```

Com esta definição, quando um cliente for deletado, todas as tabelas que dependem da tabela `tbl_CLIENTES` (têm uma foreign key que refere uma coluna na tabela `tbl_CLIENTES`) serão automaticamente actualizadas, isto é, os registos correspondentes a esse cliente serão deletados também.

```
insert into tbl_CLIENTES values
(1, 'manuel00', 'Manuel Silva'),
(2, 'maria', 'Maria Silva');

insert into tbl_CLIENTES_AGENDA values
(1, 1, 'manuel@gmail.com'),
(2, 2, 'maria@gmail.com');
```

O conteúdo das tabelas é neste momento:

```
select * from tbl_clientes;

idCliente    | loginCliente  | nome
1            | manuel        | Manuel Silva
2            | maria         | Maria Silva 

select * from tbl_clientes_agenda;    

id     |  idCliente  | email
1      |  1          | manuel@gmail.com
2      |  2          | maria@gmail.com
```

Agora apagamos um dos clientes

```
delete from tbl_CLIENTES where idCliente = 1
```

E após isto o conteúdo da tabela tbl_CLIENTES_AGENDA é o seguinte:

```
select * from tbl_clientes_agenda; 

id     |  idCliente  | email
2      |  2          | maria@gmail.com
```

Agora, basta apenas aplicar este conceito a todas as suas tabelas que têm Foreign Key.

Comment: está dando o seguinte erro : 

11:18:57 DELETE FROM tbl_PUBLICACOESxIMAGENS WHERE COD_SEQUN_IMAGM IN ('64,65,66,67,68,70,71') 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '64,65,66,67,68,70,71' 0.374 sec

Comment: Tens um erro de syntax: Não é IN ('64,65,66,67,68,70,71')  mas sim IN (64,65,66,67,68,70,71)

Comment: Boa, vlw amigo.

Comment: Ainda bem que deu para ajudar! :)